# Delimiter between multiple strings in ListView (NET.Framework. 4.7, WindowsForms)

Tags: c#, listview

I have some entries in a ListView (multiple rows, see figure 1) ). The last column lists different names and they are seperated  without commas. So far, everything‘s is fine, but how can i put a comma beetween the names and also remove the white-spaces in each line from the last column? (see figure 2))
Many thanks in advance!

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
string comma= ",";
for (int i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
{
   string lastColumn = "";               
   lastColumn += listView2.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text + comma;
                
   a.Add(lastColumn.Trim());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understend what you need, you can try something like

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                item.SubItems[2].Text = item.SubItems[2].Text.Replace(" ", ",").Trim();
            }
        }
```

Before press the button
[image: Before press the button]

After

[image: After]

Comment: This works especially well. Thank you very much!